# Can I shorten this statement to query for an item in an NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way I can eliminate the double use of `[self.definition[@"pattern-width"]` in the following statement? I want to use a value if available within an NSDictionary but use a default if it's not available.  This works...

```
self.definition[@"pattern-width"] ? [self.definition[@"pattern-width"] floatValue] : 320.0f;
```

Is there a syntax or construct I can use to shorten it further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a shorter version by using [`?:` operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3A#C)  from a GCC extension

```
[(self.definition[@"pattern-width"] ?: @320.0f) floatValue]
```

If zero is not a possible value, you can do this

```
[self.definition[@"pattern-width"] floatValue] ?: 320.f
```

Comment: Nice was trying to remember ?: operator.  Thanks.

Comment: Note, the ternary conditional operator with the middle operand omitted is a GNU C addition. While it is neat usage the understandability to most developers is confusing, not a good trait.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be:

```
NSNumber *num = self.definition[@"pattern-width"];
float val = num ? [num floatValue] : 320.0f;
```

You don't win points by cramming everything on one line. :)

Comment: No no points to be won for sure.  Was more of just a curiosity I've often wondered about.  Thanks for the reply.